# Find Matching rows in the data frame by comparing all rows based on certain conditions

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm fairly new to python and would appreciate if someone can guide me in the right direction.

I have a dataset that has unique trades in each row. I need to find all rows that match on certain conditions. Basically, find any offsetting trades that fit a certain condition. For example:

Find trades that have the same REF_RATE, RECEIVE is within a difference of 5, MATURITY_DATE is with 7 days of each other. I have attached the image of data.

Thank You.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `groupby` to achieve this. As per you requirement specific to this ask `Find trades that have the same REF_RATE, RECEIVE is within a difference of 5, MATURITY_DATE is with 7 days of each other` you can proceed like this.

```
#sample data created from the image of your dataset

>>> data = {'Maturity_Date':['2/01/2021','10/01/2021','10/01/2021','6/06/2021'],'Trade_id':['10484','12880','11798','19561'],'REF_RATE':['BBSW','BBSW','OIS','BBSW'],'Recive':[1.5,1.25,2,10]}
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data)
>>> df
  Maturity_Date Trade_id REF_RATE  Recive
0     2/01/2021    10484     BBSW    1.50
1    10/01/2021    12880     BBSW    1.25
2    10/01/2021    11798      OIS    2.00
3     6/06/2021    19561     BBSW   10.00

#convert Maturity_Date to datetime format and sort REF_RATE by date if needed

>>> df['Maturity_Date'] =  pd.to_datetime(df['Maturity_Date'], dayfirst=True)
>>> df['Maturity_Date'] = df.groupby('REF_RATE')['Maturity_Date'].apply(lambda x: x.sort_values()) #if needed
>>> df
  Maturity_Date Trade_id REF_RATE  Recive
0    2021-01-02    10484     BBSW    1.50
1    2021-01-10    12880     BBSW    1.25
2    2021-01-10    11798      OIS    2.00
3    2021-06-06    19561     BBSW   10.00

#groupby of REF_RATE and apply condition on date and receive column

>>> df['date_diff>7'] = df.groupby('REF_RATE')['Maturity_Date'].diff() / np.timedelta64(1, 'D') > 7
>>> df['rate_diff>5'] = df.groupby('REF_RATE')['Recive'].diff() > 5
>>> df
  Maturity_Date Trade_id REF_RATE  Recive  date_diff>7  rate_diff>5
0    2021-01-02    10484     BBSW    1.50        False        False
1    2021-01-10    12880     BBSW    1.25         True        False #date_diff true as for BBSW Maturity date is more than 7
2    2021-01-10    11798      OIS    2.00        False        False
3    2021-06-06    19561     BBSW   10.00         True         True #rate_diff and date_diff true because date>7 and receive difference>5
```

Comment: Apologies for the late response but I'm looking to compare 1 row with 2 row to check those conditions and if it doesn't match then move to row 3 and so on. However, if there is a match then save both rows as a pair.

Comment: @Hardeep This is what the code is doing. Question has been answered as per your ask in the question, if you expect something else apart from this you can create a new question providing all the details and the requirement